# Access Google Cloud Run through the VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn, google-cloud-run, vpc

I am trying to hide my Cloud Run application in VPN.

What I already did:

- I have created a box in VPC (vpn-gateway)
- Configured VPN there
- Configured routing to allow access all machines in VPC
- Created VPC Connecter to have a bridge between Cloud Run and my VPC
- Set 'Route all traffic through the VPC Connector' on Cloud Run
- route traffic 216.239.0.0/16 (aka Cloud Run) through the VPN

At this point it works well.

Unfortunately, I have 3 projects (prod/testing/dev). And I'd like to have one VPN for all projects.
I decided to add Shared VPC on top of all my projects. And it seems that hosts from Host (parent) project cannot access Cloud Run in Service Project.

What is best practice for hiding Cloud Run applications from 3rd party users?

Comment: Probably best to ask this on ServerFault, as this is about network infrastructure, and not programming. Just be sure to read the guidelines there, as this seems a bit opinion-based.

Comment: Did you create the VPC connector in the shared VPC or in the dedicated VPC of your project?

Comment: Originally I had connector in `default` network of the 'child' VPCs. Now, I have created new connector in shard VPC, and redeployed Cloud Run app into shared VPC. Still receiving 403 error.